# Make a list of class in python

Tags: python, list, class

I've started self-learning python and while I know C# and Java the python language is a bit strange for me right now. I'd like to make a small phonebook program.

I want to make a list called phonebook where each member in the list is from a class called entery, in each entery there are several strings and a list of strings for phone numbers. For example:

```
class entery:
    def addEntery (str1,str2,list):
        tmp = entery()
        tmp.str1 = str1
        tmp.str2 = str2
        tmp.list = list

def main():
    phonebook = []
    phonebook.append(addEntery('ian1','ian2',list)
```

I need help on closing the gap i have from C# to python, and making a class for simple tasks.

Comment: You say you have a problem, but never tell us what it is? Do you get an error? Does it not work as you expect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're not defining a proper constructor. It should be:

```
class Entery(object):
  def __init__(self, str1, str2, str3):
    self.str1 = str1
    self.str2 = str2
    self.str3 = str3
```

Since Python doesn't have "private" data, you can access each of these fields directly from the "outside":

```
>>> test = Entery("a", "b", "c")
>>> print test.str1
a
```

Then you can build a list by calling the constructor to build *instances*:

```
phonebook.append(Entery("one", "two", "three"))
phonebook.append(Entery("four", "five", "six"))
```

This is quite important: `phonebook` is a list of instances, i.e. a list of objects, not a "list of classes". It's of course possible to put classes in a list too, but that's not what you're after.

You probably should focus more on reading some basic Python class tutorial. Also, the word you're looking for when it comes to naming the class is probably `Entry`.

Comment: thx... can i go directly to the str in each entery like phonebook[0].str1 ?

Comment: @Iakovl: Yes you can. Of course you could have just tried it to see for yourself...

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing bracket on your append method which would be the source of the error. Also, all functions belonging to classes in python need to have a reference to self in the function signature, you could also shrink the class down to a simple constructor.

```
class Entery:
    def __init__(self, str1, str2, str3):
        self.str1 = str1
        self.str2 = str2
        self.str3 = str3

phonebook = []
phonebook.append(Entery('ian1','ian2',list))
print phonebook[0].str1
```